# Sending newsletters using Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We have been using the Journey Builder in following way:

First we create a Campaing on Sales Cloud, then we create a simple journey in Journey Builder (Campaign entry source and Email send activity) and after activating we were doing a bulk upload to the Sales force Campaign.

This usually works fine, but recently we noticed not all contacts in Campaign are entering the Journey, for example we add 4000 contacts to Campaign but only 2800 get entered into the Journey. We have no-re-entry setup in the Journey, so we usually delete everyone from Campain and readd them. Sometimes everyone else gets added and sometimes just a part of contacts get added to journey.

My question is following:

What is the best method of sending such newsletters to few thousand people, where we only send one email, to make sure it works fine and everyone gets into the journey without having to reupload everyone to the campaing?

Comment: Are you sending to the same audience everytime? Do you use the same campaign on SalesCloud or create a new one for every send?

Comment: We have many different journeys and always create a new campaign with different campaign members for each send

Comment: I don't fully understand your use case. If you are creating a new campaign each time then why are you deleting everyone from the campaign and add them back?

Comment: So I don’t want to do that, but I use this as workaround if not all Campaign members are injected into journey. This is what happens: I want to do a send, so I create a Campaign, then create Journey, activate it and then I add my Campaign members. For example I add 4000, but in Journey I only see that 2800 came through. What I want, is that when I add 4000, in the Journey also all 4000 is added.

Comment: If your logic is to only send an email to your campaign members, why don't you try Campaigns Sends? check out the help https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_send_to_campaigns_or_reports.htm&type=5